# Match everything after end of a line and before start of another line

Tags: regex

I am trying to match everything between 2 words 
 1. AM at the end of a line 
 2. DR at the beginning of a line

```
Date:11/18/2016:9:39 AM
NIP CR/JUPITER, WHITE/GIN
DR Size:1200mb
```

With the expected outcome -> `NIP CR/JUPITER, WHITE/GIN`

I was able to get this done using a combination of lookbehind and lookahead `(?<=(?:AM|PM))[\s\S]*?(?=DR)` however this regex would not work for in some scenarios like this below

```
Date:11/18/2016:9:39 AM
NIP CR/DRAIN, WHITE/GIN
DR Size:1200mb
```

Comment: Try `AM\n(.*)\nDR` https://regex101.com/r/S8ZfDd/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example has DR in DRAIN. You could add a newline before `DR` and perhaps also add a word boundary after `DR\b` to prevent being part of a larger word:

```
(?<=(?:AM|PM))[\s\S]*?(?=\nDR)
                         ^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S8ZfDd/2)

But could also move the newline to the positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=(?:AM|PM)\n).*(?=\nDR\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S8ZfDd/4)

You might also match AM followed by a newline, capture the next line in a capturing group followed by matching a newline and DR:

```
AM\n(.*)\nDR
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S8ZfDd/1)

Comment: The second option is alot cleaner, would there be a way to ignore the AM and DR?

Comment: @Amanni Do you mean like this? `(?<=(?:AM|PM)\n).*(?=\nDR\b)` https://regex101.com/r/S8ZfDd/4 I have added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### RegEx 1

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/kQBGhF/1) might help you to do so by creating one group (`$1`) where your target line is.

```
AM\n(.+)\nDR
```

[image]

#### RegEx 2

Another approach is to target the second line directly such as [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/Ku2iG1/1)

```
[A-Z]{3}\s[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+.+
```

[image]

You can also use group `()` and call it using `$1`:

```
([A-Z]{3}\s[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+.+)
```

#### RegEx 3

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/X2JZmN/1) creates one group by adding additional boundaries to the pattern:

```
([A-Z]{3}\s[A-Z]+\/[A-Z,]+\s[A-Z,\/]+)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that your second and third regex do not take the pattern at the end of the line and at the start of the next line into account. They also match when you omit the first and the third line. Your first regex is the same as in my answer.